# NSURLSessionConfiguration timeoutIntervalForRequest doesn't seem to work with the background session

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

The new timeout property of NSURLSessionConfiguration doesn't seem to work when the session is set to work in background (via backgroundSessionConfiguration call).

Anybody know if that's really the case?

Code snippet:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:bgSessionConfigIdentifier];
sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60;
```

Do I need to do anything extra for the timeout to work?

Comment: I'm seeing this behaviour as well.

Comment: Filed a radar 15856876

Comment: Great! Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into similar problem, fixed it by using 
timeoutIntervalForResource 
instead of 
timeoutIntervalForRequest

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfigurationbackgroundSessionConfiguration:bgSessionConfigIdentifier];
sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60;
```